# Highcharts, Highstock and Highmaps

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

On November 17th I requested that [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) be given [two new synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/highcharts/synonyms): [highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highstock) and [highmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highmaps). This has received no attention. I'm posting here to justify why I feel this should be done:

#### Why should these synonyms be made?

1. They're all maintained by one company, Highsoft (okay, this is a terrible reason for synonymisation).
2. All have incredibly similar APIs with lots of shared properties ([Highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts), [Highstock](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock), [Highmaps](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps)).
3. A lot of [highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highstock) and [highmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highmaps) questions are only given the [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) tag (as an example of this, there are [229 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhighcharts%5D%20stock%20-%5Bhighstock%5D%20is%3Aquestion) which include the word "stock" but are only tagged as [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts)).
4. 83% of [highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highstock) questions are also tagged [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) (1,484/1,796).
5. 78% of [highmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highmaps) questions are also tagged [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) (161/206).
6. 8 questions feature all three tags.

#### Why should [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) be the main tag?

1. The website for all three products is http://www.highcharts.com (they don't own the other two product names as .com domains).
2. Highcharts is the original product.
3. [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) has seven times more questions than [highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highstock) and [highmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highmaps) combined.

---

As far as I can tell, the only downside to making these synonyms is that their support page (http://www.highcharts.com/support) mentions the [highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highstock) and [highmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highmaps) tags. That said though, it only links directly to the [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) tag and doesn't link to the others.

Comment: I've used Highstock and Highcharts, but not Highmaps. Highstock is actually a superset of Highcharts - if you include the Highstock files in your application, you get all of Highcharts. I'd favor, at a minimum, making Highcharts the master tag for Highstock. I can't speak for Highmaps, since I've never used it. It may be different enough to warrant its own tag.

Comment: None of the reasons provided make a strong case for synonymization. This seems like the equivalent of saying that approximately half of all jquery questions are also tagged javascript, so jquery should be a synonym of javascript. Just because to things are closely related does not mean that they are actually the same thing.

Comment: @TinyGiant the difference between JavaScript and jQuery is that they are radically different, whereas all three of these fundamentally use identical code (thus why I linked to each of their APIs). The question "how do I get an element by it's ID?" would have completely different answers between JavaScript (`document.getElementById(...)`) and jQuery (`$("#...")[0]`), but the question "how do I access all charts on my page?" would have the same answer for all three (`Highcharts.charts`).

Comment: Are there methods that are available for highstock and highmaps that are not available through highcharts itself?

Comment: @TinyGiant most of the differences are visual. Highstock and Highmaps are essentially wrappers on top of Highcharts. Highstock and Highmaps can do everything Highcharts can do, but with a few extra features. For Highstock, these are noted here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highstock. Highmaps extends Highcharts by adding geographic charts.

Comment: So both API's contain methods that are not available in highcharts itself. That means they are not exactly the same thing. Synonyms are for things that are exactly the same, not mostly the same with some differences.

Comment: Was approved by the community through voting some years ago.